# Customize .msi package to include config file and a script

Tags: windows-installer

I am trying to customize the NSclient++ .msi package to include a site specific config file and add a script to the scripts folder when it installs. I also want to avoid the prompts about what features to install and such. Please help!

I did some research and come across tools like Orca, MSI Studio, Admin Studio etc, and I learnt that you can create a transform, but what do I do after that? How can I merge the transform to the original msi?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways of creating a transform and then there are ways to permanently apply a transform to an MSI.  In other words take MSI v1.0 (input) and create a transform then apply the transform to a copy of v1.0 (output).  Later apply the transform to a copy of v2.0 (output) and see if it still works without recreating the transform.  You might be able to do this you might not depending on what changes from 1.0 to 2.0.

There are tools such as InstallShield that let you make your changes using a UI and Window Installer has an API for creating custom tools for automating this process.  I've written such tools internally that I have not released as open source.

Then there is the matter of the changes themselves.  A config file and script probably means compressing files into a CAB and embedding in the MSI along with updates to the Component, File and Media tables.  Getting rid of dialogs would likely be updates to the ControlEvent table to rewrite the dialog flow.

This is a very broad question and can't be "answered" in it's current form beyond the overview that I've given.  This is about 4 hours work for an MSI expert and weeks of rampup time for a novice.

Comment: Thank you for the overview, Christopher. I have install shield installed. I just right clicked the .msi package to open with Install shield and it opened in it's GUI. I see that I am able to add the required files by navigating to Application Data - > File and Folders. When I added my file it asked me 2 questions, 1. On the source media ( Uncompressed ) 2. In a new CAB file with stream CAB into the Windows Install package check box, There is also a check box at the bottom which asks for Extract COM information. If you would like me to contact you  directly that would be good.